# Make a smooth transition between width of div

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a `div` which contain my sidebar. To toggle it, I use a boolean, so when the user click on a the chevron, the width value change from `24rem` to `6rem` and vice versa.
The toggle being immediate, I would like to make it smooth. I though adding a transition to my css could make it but nothing change. Is there  a method to make a smooth transition between two value without using an external library.

This is the div I have.

```js
<div className={`${isToggle ? 'w-24' : 'w-96'} transition ease-linear duration-200 h-full`}>
```